# Parametros de reduce - Javascript

Tags: javascript

No entiendo este algoritmo, ¿Por qué se pasa un array [curr, prev], este array es lo mismo que los primeros dos argumentos de la funcion reduce? accumulator y currentValue?, y en seguida otro argumento num? Seria lo mismo que el current index que se le pasa a la funcion de reduce? y al ultimo se pasa otro array [0], qué significa este ultimo array?

```js
const rob = nums => nums.reduce( ([curr, prev], num) => 
  [Math.max(curr, prev + num), curr], [0, 0])[0];

console.log('rob', rob([1, 2, 3, 1]))
```

Comment: esta pregunta no esta clara con lo que dices, opto por que elimines la pregunta y con tu reputacion puedes entrar al [chat]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que tu confusión se debe a que el primer parámetro (acumulador) se [desestructura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) en dos variables:

```
// Desestructurar valores y asignar a variables
let [curr, prev] = [1, 5];
console.log(curr, prev);
```

Esto es lo mismo que:

```
let acumulador = [1, 5];
let curr = acumulador[0];
let prev = acumulador[1];
```

Pero evitas tener declarar cada variable o acceder a cada elemento por su índice en el arreglo.

```js
const rob = nums => nums.reduce(
  // El acumulador es un solo parámetro [elemento1, elemento2]
  // Pero se desesestructura en dos variables
  // - curr es el primer elemento del acumulador
  // - prev es el segundo elemento del acumulador
  // num (segundo parámetro) es el número actual en el ciclo
  ([curr, prev], num) => {
      // Ver valores antes de realizar modificaciones
      console.log(curr, prev, num);
      // Actualizar acumulador (arreglo de dos elementos)
      return [Math.max(curr, prev + num), curr];
  },
  [0, 0] // El acumulador se inicializa como un arreglo con dos elementos
)[0]; // Se obtiene solo el primer elemento del acumulador (curr)


console.log('rob', rob([1, 2, 3, 1]));
```

Comment: Gracias @Triby!, no sabia de la desestructuracion del acumulador.